# MongoDB Nested GroupBy

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I have a sample data like below:
(Every floor has multiple sensor data)

```
{"Floor_Id": "Galileo_001",
    "name": "Forklifts",
    "Sensor_data": [{
            "Floor_Id": "Galileo_001",
            "Floor_name": "Forklifts",
            "Name": "forkLift_002",
            "Asset_Id": 123,
            "Load": 1.7096133,
            "Timestamp": 1537878750996
        },
        {
            "Floor_Id": "Galileo_001",
            "Floor_name": "Forklifts",
            "Name": "forkLift_003",
            "Asset_Id": 456,
            "Load": 1.7096133,
            "Timestamp": 1537878750996,
        },
        {
            "Floor_Id": "Galileo_001",
            "Floor_name": "Forklifts",
            "Name": "forkLift_005 ",
            "Asset_Id": 127,
            "Load": 1.7096133,
            "Timestamp": 1537878750996
        },
        {
            "Floor_Id": "Galileo_001",
            "Floor_name": "Forklifts",
            "Name": "forkLift_001",
            "Asset_Id": 157,
            "Load": 1.7096133,
            "Timestamp": 1537878750996,
        }
]}
```

For the response, I need total load calculated for every floor and individual load for every day. The desired response is like below:

```
{
    "TotalLoad": 3214,
    "Floor_Id": "Galileo_001",
    "LoadUnit": "Kgs",
    "AssetStatus": [{
        "TotalLoad": 200,
        "LoadUnit": "Kgs",
        "Date": "1539588994"
    }, {
        "TotalLoad": 400,
        "LoadUnit": "Kgs",
        "Date": "1539475200"
    }, {
        "TotalLoad": 100,
        "LoadUnit": "Kgs",
        "Date": "1539388800"
    }]
}
```

I am writing the below Mongo aggregation:

```
db.sensordata.aggregate([{"$unwind" : "$Sensor_data" },
{"$group": {
     "_id": {"Floor_Id": "$Floor_Id", 
         "DailyDate":{"$dateFromParts":{
                    "year":{"$year":{"$add": [new Date("1970-01-01"), "$Sensor_data.Timestamp"]}},
                    "month":{"$month":{"$add": [new Date("1970-01-01"), "$Sensor_data.Timestamp"]}},
                    "day":{"$dayOfMonth":{"$add": [new Date("1970-01-01"), "$Sensor_data.Timestamp"]}}
                      } 
                  }
             },
     "AssetLoad": {"$sum": "$Sensor_data.Load" }
    }
},
{
    "$group" : {
            "_id": {"Floor_Id": "$_id.Floor_Id"},
            "TotalLoad": { "$sum": "$Sensor_data.Load" },
            "AssetStatus":{
                "$push":{
                    "TotalLoad": "$AssetLoad",
                    "LoadUnit": "Kgs",
                    "Date": "$_id.DailyDate"
                    }
                }
        }
}
])
```

**Problem:**
For the total load calculated for every floor, I am getting 0.

```
{
    "_id" : {
        "Floor_Id" : "Galileo_001"
    },
    "TotalLoad" : 0,
    "AssetStatus" : [ 
        {
            "TotalLoad" : 8.5480665,
            "LoadUnit" : "Kgs",
            "Date" : ISODate("2018-09-25T00:00:00.000Z")
        }
    ]
}
```

What am I doing wrong here?
How can I get the desired output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're getting zero because the second `$group` pipeline does not recognise the field `Sensor_data.Load` so it defaults to 0.

Replace the expression

```
"TotalLoad": { "$sum": "$Sensor_data.Load" },
```

with the pipeline-changed field `AssetLoad`

```
"TotalLoad": { "$sum": "$AssetLoad" },
```

---

To calculate the number of sensors each floor has in total, your first pipeline needs to calculate the size of the 
sensor data using **[`$size`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/size/)**, store that in a new field using **[`$addFields`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/addFields/#pipe._S_addFields)** then retain the field in the preceding pipeline stages pipelines by using the **[`$first`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/first/)** operators.audit

Amend your pipeline to the following:

```
db.sensordata.aggregate([
    { "$addFields": {
      "TotalSensors": { "$size": "Sensor_data" }
    } },
    {"$unwind" : "$Sensor_data" },
    { "$group": {
      "_id": {
          "Floor_Id": "$Floor_Id", 
          "DailyDate": {
              "$dateFromParts": {
                  "year": { "$year": {
                      "$add": [new Date("1970-01-01"), "$Sensor_data.Timestamp"]
                  } },
                  "month": { "$month": {
                      "$add": [new Date("1970-01-01"), "$Sensor_data.Timestamp"]
                  } },
                  "day": { "$dayOfMonth": {
                      "$add": [new Date("1970-01-01"), "$Sensor_data.Timestamp"]
                  } }
              } 
          }
      },
      "AssetLoad": {"$sum": "$Sensor_data.Load" },
      "TotalSensors": { "$first": "$TotalSensors" }
    } },
    { "$group" : {
        "_id": {"Floor_Id": "$_id.Floor_Id"},
        "TotalLoad": { "$sum": "$Sensor_data.Load" },
        "AssetStatus":{
            "$push": {
              "TotalLoad": "$AssetLoad",
              "LoadUnit": "Kgs",
              "Date": "$_id.DailyDate"
            }
        },
        "TotalSensors": { "$first": "$TotalSensors" }
    } }
])
```

Comment: What if I want to calculate how many sensors each floor has in total?

Comment: I've updated my answer but in general it's considered bad practice here on SO to change the answers after a different question is posted as it can be very misleading to future readers who can see that the answers provided do not match what's been asked. See [meta post about this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/296489/)